# Why does pandas 2min bucket print NaN although all my row values are numbers (not NaN)?

Tags: python, pandas

I know that in my data response_bytes column does not have NaN values because when I run: `data[data.response_bytes.isna()].count()` I get as a result 0.

When I then run 2 min bucket mean and then head I get NaN:

```
print(data.reset_index().set_index('time').resample('2min').mean().head())

                     index  identity  user  http_code  response_bytes  unknown
time                                                                          
2018-01-31 09:26:00    0.5       NaN   NaN      200.0           264.0      NaN
2018-01-31 09:28:00    NaN       NaN   NaN        NaN             NaN      NaN
2018-01-31 09:30:00    NaN       NaN   NaN        NaN             NaN      NaN
2018-01-31 09:32:00    NaN       NaN   NaN        NaN             NaN      NaN
2018-01-31 09:34:00    NaN       NaN   NaN        NaN             NaN      NaN
```

Why do response byte time bucketing mean have NaN values?

I wanted to experiment and learn how time bucketing works in pandas.  So I used the log file: `http://www.cs.tufts.edu/comp/116/access.log` as input data, then loaded it into pandas DataFrame and then applied time bucket 2 min (for the first time in my life) and ran mean(), I wasn't expecting to see any NaN in the **response_bytes** column because all values are not NaN.

Here is my full code:

```
import urllib.request
import pandas as pd
import re
from datetime import datetime
import pytz

pd.set_option('max_columns',10)

def parse_str(x):
    """
    Returns the string delimited by two characters.

    Example:
        `>>> parse_str('[my string]')`
        `'my string'`
    """
    return x[1:-1]

def parse_datetime(x):
    '''
    Parses datetime with timezone formatted as:
        `[day/month/year:hour:minute:second zone]`

    Example:
        `>>> parse_datetime('13/Nov/2015:11:45:42 +0000')`
        `datetime.datetime(2015, 11, 3, 11, 45, 4, tzinfo=<UTC>)`

    Due to problems parsing the timezone (`%z`) with `datetime.strptime`, the
    timezone will be obtained using the `pytz` library.
    '''
    dt = datetime.strptime(x[1:-7], '%d/%b/%Y:%H:%M:%S')
    dt_tz = int(x[-6:-3])*60+int(x[-3:-1])
    return dt.replace(tzinfo=pytz.FixedOffset(dt_tz))

# data = pd.read_csv(StringIO(accesslog))
url = "http://www.cs.tufts.edu/comp/116/access.log"
accesslog =  urllib.request.urlopen(url).read().decode('utf-8')
fields = ['host', 'identity', 'user', 'time_part1', 'time_part2', 'cmd_path_proto', 
          'http_code', 'response_bytes', 'referer', 'user_agent', 'unknown']

data = pd.read_csv(url, sep=' ', header=None, names=fields, na_values=['-'])

# Panda's parser mistakenly splits the date into two columns, so we must concatenate them
time = data.time_part1 + data.time_part2
time_trimmed = time.map(lambda s: re.split('[-+]', s.strip('[]'))[0]) # Drop the timezone for simplicity
data['time'] = pd.to_datetime(time_trimmed, format='%d/%b/%Y:%H:%M:%S')

data.head()

print(data.reset_index().set_index('time').resample('2min').mean().head())
```

I was expecting the time-bucketing of the mean of response_bytes column not to be NaN.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is expected behaviour, because [`resampling`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#resampling) converts to a regular time interval, so if there are no samples you get `NaN`.

So it means there are no datetimes between some 2 minutes itervals, e.g. `2018-01-31 09:28:00` and `2018-01-31 09:30:00`, so `mean` cannot be count and get `NaN`s.

```
print (data[data['time'].between('2018-01-31 09:28:00','2018-01-31 09:30:00')])
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [host, identity, user, time_part1, time_part2, cmd_path_proto,
          http_code, response_bytes, referer, user_agent, unknown, time]
Index: []

[0 rows x 12 columns]
```